# unsigned binary arithmetic. Subtraction and square it

Tags: integer-arithmetic

We have two variables:

`unsigned int a=5;`
`unsigned int b=3;`

We know, that

```
a-b==~(b-a)+1
```

But how to prove, that

`(a-b)*(a-b)==(b-a)*(b-a)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of `a-b==~(b-a)+1` I would use that ℤ/2<sup>k</sup>ℤ is a [ring](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ring_(mathematics)). That `(a-b)*(a-b)==(b-a)*(b-a)` in a ring is already known, but you could start with `(a + -b)*(a + -b)=(b + -a)*(b + -a)` and take it from there:

Work out the first product using distributivity: `(a*a)+(a*-b)+(-b*a)+(-b*-b)`

Work out the second product: `(b*b)+(b*-a)+(-a*b)+(-a*-a)`

It is a known fact that in rings, `-x*y = x*-y = -(x*y)`, and `--x = x`, use that to simplify a bit:

L: `(a*a)+-(a*b)+-(b*a)+(b*b)`
R: `(b*b)+-(b*a)+-(a*b)+(a*a)`

Then just rearrange it a bit.